# Convert Dicom image to to jpg,png

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have to convert a `DICOM` image into any supportable format for `UIImageView` such as JPG, PNG, etc. Are there any frameworks to implement in iOS for iPad?

I found ITK useful to do this but still I don't know how use ITK to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only opensource DICOM library I know of is [Imebra](http://imebra.com); it claims support for Windows and OSX only, but as a C++ library I can't foresee any major difficulties with porting it to iOS.

Answer (score 1):

There is one open source Lib "GDCM", you can check this ANS [How to display DICOM files in a view on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642063/how-to-display-dicom-files-in-a-view-on-iphone).

Even i have not tried my self, but seems to be right way to go.

By the way, have you tried what "Benjamin Mayo" answered ? was ***imebra*** usful to you ?